# I need to remove the backslashes from the following string which is a URL I have in a data frame in R

Tags: r

Can someone help me fix this? I am trying to remove the backslashes and the numbers between them from the following string.

```
a<-c("/organization/energystone-games-100-a\307\201\265\347\377\263\306\270\270\306\210\217")
```

I want to remove the backslashes and the numbers so the expected result should look like below:

```
/organization/energystone-games-100-a
```

Comment: `sub("(.*-\\w+).*","\\1",a)`?

Comment: Does `a` appear the way it does above in your `a<-c(...)` expression? When I copy that into my R, it converts each `\###` into a special character so that `a` actually looks like this: `/organization/energystone-games-100-aÇµçÿ³Æ¸¸Æˆ`.  Is that just my system, or could it be part of the reason you're having trouble?

Comment: Occurring on system as well.The problem is likely a function of how you're reading your data in.

Comment: Thanks for answering, i used the gsub() suggested by G. Grothendieck and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually no backslashes in the input.  Backslash followed by digits is how R renders certain special characters.  To remove them remove each character that is not lower case letter, upper case letter, digit, slash or minus.

```
gsub("[^a-zA-Z0-9/-]", "", a)
## [1] "/organization/energystone-games-100-a"
```

Actually no upper case letters appear so if you are only concerned about such strings then the pattern could be reduced to `"[^a-z0-9/-]"` .

Comment: Thank you very much sir.It worked.Yes you are right it appears R is rendering the special characters as backslashes, as in the console it shows backslashes however in the UI tab window it shows the following symbols in place of backslashes i.e '<' and '>'...I used UTF-8 and Latin-1 to import the .txt file.I think the encoding bit was ok ? I found these backslashes issue when I was comparing the columns with another data frame.